# execute MySQL query from the terminal without printing results

Tags: mysql, terminal

I am performing some MySQL queries that have very large result sets. I would like to see how long they take, but I don't want all the output to be printed on my terminal because it takes up a lot of space and time. I can do this by writing a script that performs and times the query, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this directly through MySQL on the terminal. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your query in `set @foo = (select count(*) from (  .....   ) foo)`

Comment: this only seems to work for a single value which really limits the query

Comment: @ejectamenta: if you just have a single value, it can be shortened to `set @foo = (.....)`; with the select count...foo wrapper around it, you can put selects that return multiple values where I have `.....`

Answer (score 20):

Change the pager in mysql like indicated here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/01/21/fun-with-the-mysql-pager-command/

`mysql> pager cat > /dev/null` will discard the output, and `mysql> pager` will put it back.

Answer (score -1):

Just run mysql console utility, then enter **source file_name** (where file_name contains sql commands)

Comment: I created a test.sql that has a simple command (select * from table limit 100) and ran "source test.sql". It runs the command, but still prints out the output.